# How to watch only first level in an angular scope variable

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have  an array in angular -

```
$scope.data = [
               { a:1, b:2},
               {a:{b:{c:5}}}
              ]
```

Now I don't want to watch every single value under data.
I always change data object completely -

```
$scope.data = data;
```

So how can I reduce the number of angular watchers here?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Angular 1 watchers work.

AngularJS creates watchers when you actually *watch* stuff (like `$scope.data[0].a`) and it only watches *that thing*. If you have a million value array and watch `$scope.data[0].b` when you `.$digest` (or `$apply`) it will go through each such watcher (typically defined with $watch or inside `{{}}`s or events) and check if its value changed (dirty checking), it does nothing to $scope.data as a whole.

So to summarize:

- Watchers are only creates when you *watch* stuff.
- When watchers are run, they only check if the value changes.
- The size of your array or how you manipulate it is irrelevant as the number of watchers you have is determined by your observing code and not your data defining code.

See this [slightly aged but still mostly correct post](http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html) about how watchers work.